# extract a substring in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string:

```
"hello this.is.a.test(MainActivity.java:47)"
```

and I want to be able to extract the **MainActivity.java:47** 
(everything that is inside '(' and ')' and only the first occurance).

I tried with regex but it seems that I am doing something wrong.

Thanks

Comment: posiible duplicates of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749549/extract-substring-in-java-using-regex and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662215/java-how-to-extract-a-substring-using-regex

Comment: Do you specifically _need_ to use a regex, or is any working method sufficient?

Comment: it looks like you're trying to parse a stacktrace. It comes from a text file, or do you have access to the Exception object being created?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it yourself:

```
int pos1 = str.indexOf('(') + 1;
int pos2 = str.indexOf(')', pos1);

String result = str.substring(pos1, pos2)
```

Or you can use commons-lang which contains a very nice `StringUtils` class that has `substringBetween()`

Comment: I think you need to replace the line: `int pos1 = str.lastIndexOf('(') + 1;` with `int pos1 = str.indexOf('(') + 1;`. The OP wants only the first occurence.

Comment: @Toader: Maybe. I've upvoted your comment to make it more prominent. That way, the OP can decided what he needs.

Comment: thanks ..  This is what he said: "and only the first occurance."

Answer (score 1):

I think Regex is a liitle bit an overkill. I would use something like this:

```
String input = "hello this.is.a.test(MainActivity.java:47)";
String output = input.subString(input.lastIndexOf("(") + 1, input.lastIndexOf(")"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
^[^\\(]*\\(([^\\)]+)\\)
```

The result is in the first group.

Comment: Sure you *could* do it with a regex, but when it looks like that, why bother?

Comment: ACtually the actual regex is much simpler :). I just complicated it to make sure it works as intended :). This will work too: `\\((.+?)\\)`

Comment: Two reasons to bother about regexes: the "lastIndexOf" method will iterate over the chars of the string twice (once for the "(", once for the ")") while a good regex implementation will iterate over the chars just once (twice, in the worst case, depending on the output). The second is that you may have unbalanced (). In the special case of the OP, they are balance so my second point is moot.

Comment: ... and the doubled backslashes are not part of the regexp, only necessary for the Java String literal.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer for your question :

```
String str = "hello this.is.a.test(MainActivity.java:47) another.test(MyClass.java:12)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z][\\w]+\\.java:\\d+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m=p.matcher(str);

if(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

The RegExp explained :

`[a-z][\w]+\.java:\d+`

[a-z]   > Check that we start with a letter ...
[\w]+  > ... followed by a letter, a digit or an underscore...
\.java: > ... followed exactly by the string ".java:"...
\d+      > ... ending by one or more digit(s)

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-code:

```
int p1 = location of '('
int p2 = location of ')', starting the search from p1
String s = extract string from p1 to p2
```

[String.indexOf()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) and [String.substring()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) are your friends.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String input = "hello this.is.a.test(MainActivity.java:47) (and some more text)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\)]*\\(([^\\)]*)\\).*");
Matcher m = p.matcher( input );
if(m.matches()) {
  System.out.println(m.group( 1 )); //output: MainActivity.java:47
}
```

This also finds the first occurence of text between ( and ) if there are more of them.

Note that in Java you normally have the expressions wrapped with `^` and `$` implicitly (or at least the same effect), i.e. the regex must match the entire input string. Thus `[^\\)]*` at the beginning and `.*` at the end are necessary.