# How do you extract a substring from a string based on an input regex

Tags: java, regex

Given a string `s`, and a regex `r`, how can we extract the substring from `s` that matches the regex `r`?

Comment: generally before asking question on StackOverflow u r supposed to put some efforts!

Comment: atleast google for your question first
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749549/extract-substring-in-java-using-regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Build a regexp like this :**

> .+?(r).*

where `r` is you regexp.

**Java Code**

```
String s;// Your string
String r;// Your regexp
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(String.format(".+?(%s).*",r));
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

**Note**
I assume your regexp will be matched only one time in your string `s`.

Comment: It is unnecessary to add the .+? or the .* around the (s), with them it will only match a single occurrence and it will be necessary for there to be at least 1 or more characters before the string he is looking to match.  Simply using '(s)' as the regex will find all occurrences of that exact string.  If indeed he is looking for only a single occurrence then .*?(%s).* would be a better solution because it would allow the substring to be at the start of the line.

Answer (score 5):

Start by reading the javadocs:

[Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

[Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can refer groups in ReEx documentation :
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg

```
    CharSequence inputStr = "abbabcd";
String patternStr = "(a(b*))+(c*)";

// Compile and use regular expression
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
boolean matchFound = matcher.find();

if (matchFound) {
    // Get all groups for this match
    for (int i=0; i<=matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        String groupStr = matcher.group(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Matcher.find](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) and [Matcher.group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28%29)

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(r);
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
   String extracted = m.group();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use round brackets in your pattern and get it via `Matcher.find/Matcher.group`. You'll address the n'th bracket with a number.

```
Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(substring_here)");
String mystr = "substring_here";
String substring;

Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(mystr); 
while (m.find()) {
    // group(1) will match the first bracket                        
substring = m.group(1);
}
```